# Use of shutdownNow in Concurrent framework

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, executors

If i am using `Futures` like

```
List<Future<String>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
```

or

```
Future<String> res = executorService.submit(new SingleWorker());
System.out.println(res.get());
```

the system waits for the tasks to complete.

Even if i had `executorService.shutdownNow();` after the statements mentioned above, i really don't understand when will the system forcefully terminate the existing threads as mentioned in the documentation since, the system never reaches the line **until the tasks are completed and a future is returned**.
Am i missing something ? Is there a different test case scenario to test it ?

Will `shutdownNow` work only with `Runnable` i.e. when we say 
`executorService.submit(new MyRunnable())` ?

**EDIT:**

I tried few different things and found out that

a)`shutdownNow` doesn't work with `invokeAll`.

b)`shutdownNow` if present after `Future.get` then the statement `shutdownNow` is blocked **until** `Future` is resolved (In case of `Callable`).

c)`shutdownNow` works perfectly with `Runnable`.

Following is my code written to test:

```
class SingleRunnableWorker implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("SingleRunnableWorker Running..");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("SingleRunnableWorker Running after sleep..");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class SingleCallableWorker implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SingleCallableWorker Calling..");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("SingleCallableWorker Calling after sleep..");
        return "SingleCallableWorker Calling done";
    }

}
```

and i am testing it as follows:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
/*List<Future<String>> results = */executorService.invokeAll(tasks);//blocks by default

Future<String> res = executorService.submit(new SingleCallableWorker());
//System.out.println(res.get()); //blocks if uncommented

executorService.submit(new SingleRunnableWorker());

executorService.shutdownNow();
```

where tasks are all `Callables`.

Bottomline is `invokeAll` and `Future.get` are blocking operations. Can someone please validate ?

Comment: `shutdownNow` will attempt to stop the threads executing the work you submit to the corresponding `ExecutorService`. Presumably, there are separate threads doing `Future#get()`.

Comment: "forcefully terminate?" not really, read the doc: "There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate."

Answer (score 1):

Both `Runnbale` and `Callable` you submitted to `ThreadPoolExecutor` will be wrappered as `java.util.concrrent.FutureTask` and executed.

In this case, in both `SingleRunnableWorker` and `SingleCallableWorker`, when task is blocked by `Thread.sleep(10000)`, `executorService.shutdownNow()` will cause InterruptedException be thrown immediately.

But,

- `InterruptedException` thrown in `SingleRunnableWorker.run()` is
  forced to be catched immediately and handled by  `e.printStackTrace()`.
- `InterruptedException` thrown in `SingleCallableWorker.call()` will
  be catched by inner syncronizer in `FutureTask`, the syncronizer just
  record InterruptedException and return. When `future.get()` is called, the
  InterruptedException will be wrappered as ExecutionException and
  re-thrown.